# Handler with ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, handler

Im am trying to create a delayed action, when I touch the Display for more than 5 Seonds.
I am using a Handler and a Runnable for this, using `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);`
I also want a ProgressBar, to show, when the Handler will kickoff. From researching i found, that i have to Override the `handleMessage()` method.. this is what i tried.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        progress.setProgress(progress.getProgress() + 100);
        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
    }
};
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        playAlarm();
    }
};

...

progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Execute Runnable after 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds.
        progress.setProgress(0);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        mBooleanIsPressed = true;
    }

    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (mBooleanIsPressed) {
            mBooleanIsPressed = false;
            progress.setProgress(0);
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is not crashing. But the ProgressBar is simply not showing anything.

Comment: I'm only ever seeing you setProgress to 0.  Where are you setting it to anything else?

Comment: on `handleMessage()` of handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use a handler there some things missing, this should work (not tested):

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    progress.setProgress(progress.getProgress() + 100);
    if (mBooleanIsPressed)
        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
}
};
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    playAlarm();
}
};

...

progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
// only start your handler if the view isn't touched
if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !mBooleanIsPressed) {
    // Execute Runnable after 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds.
    progress.setProgress(0);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    // send the first empty message, which will be handled...
    sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
    mBooleanIsPressed = true;
}

if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    if (mBooleanIsPressed) {
        mBooleanIsPressed = false;
        progress.setProgress(0);
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
return true;
}
```

feel free to ask if you have any questions